# Show null values on MYSQL Query and left join

Tags: php, mysql, join, row, left-join

i have this query:

```
SELECT 
    pupils.id_pupil
  , name
  , surname
  , (select round(avg(qualifications.calificacion),2) from qualifications where id_pupil = pupils.id_pupil and qualifications.id_trimester=incidents.id_trimester and type_qualification='class') as media
  , (select count(calificacion) from qualifications where id_pupil = pupils.id_pupil and qualifications.id_trimester=incidents.id_trimester and type_qualification='class') as count
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='miss' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as misses
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='delay' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as delays
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='attitude' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as attitude
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='miss_justif' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as misses_justificadas 
FROM 
    pupils 
    left join incidents         ON incidents.id_pupil=pupils.id_pupil
WHERE 
    level=1
    and class='A' 
    and id_trimester=1 
GROUP BY id_pupil
```

Tables:

```
pupils: (id_pupil, name, surname, email, user, pass, level, class)
incidents: (id_incidents, date, time, type_incident, comments, id_pupil, id_user, subject, id_trimester)
qualifications: (id_qualification, qualification, date, time, subject, id_pupil, id_user, id_trimester, type_qualification)
```

It works, but it doesn´t show the rows with misses, delays, attitude and misses_justif with the four values to 0. That row is omitted.

How can i show all the rows?

Thanks!

Comment: your SUMs is totally messed up. You have the very same conditions on your where statement, those on SUM is not needed.

Comment: Could you post the incidents table?

Comment: @RubenGiaquinto I´ve already posted the tables

Comment: The reason you get no records back in this situation is because your WHERE clause checks id_trimester which is on the LEFT JOINed incidents table. If are no incidents this field has a NULL value, so in effect you have done an INNER JOIN by checking it to be 1. You need to check it in the sub queries instead. But I would suggest using some code similar to that given below by @JorgeCampos which eliminates the sub queries in the select clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has some problems. I made a modification that maybe it you give you the results you want. Maybe you should put the name and surname and media and count values on your group by, but it is up to you because it depends on your requirements.

```
SELECT 
 pupils.id_pupil
 , name
 , surname
 , IFNULL(qua.media, 0) media
 , IFNULL(qua.count, 0) count
 , sum( case when type_incident='miss' then 1 else 0 end ) as misses
 , sum( case when type_incident='delay' then 1 else 0 end ) as delays
 , sum( case when type_incident='attitude' then 1 else 0 end ) as attitude
 , sum( case when type_incident='miss_justif' then 1 else 0 end ) 
 as misses_justificadas 
FROM 
 pupils 
 LEFT JOIN incidents ON incidents.id_pupil=pupils.id_pupil
 LEFT JOIN
 (select id_pupil, id_trimester, 
 count(qualification) count, 
 round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2) media
 from qualifications 
 where type_qualification='class'
 group by id_pupil, id_trimester ) as qua
 ON ( qua.id_pupil = pupils.id_pupil )
WHERE 
 level=1
 and class='A' 
 and qua.id_trimester=1 
GROUP BY pupils.id_pupil
```

Comment: I guess you are Spanish and I´m too, if you don´t mind i answer in Spanish.

Comment: El id_trimester=1 me falla ya que dice que es ambiguo. Si lo quito, me funciona bien y no altera los resultados, el problema es que sigue sin mostrarme las filas con todos los valores de las incidencias a 0. Esas filas me las salta, no sé por qué :S

Comment: See my edit. Fix that problem. Happens cause as I added a new subquery with this value it bacame ambiguos. So you have to specify from which table it is.

Comment: In order to help you better you should create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your table structure and some data sample (does not need all just the values that can attend you on your requirements)

Comment: @AlonsoGonzálezNestal I'm a Brazilian. I can understand spanish very well but I can't write it.

Comment: The pupils table doesn't have the id_trimester column. Think the check for this needs to be moved from the WHERE clause to the first ON clause (for the incidents table).

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, first at all, sorry because i thought you were Spanish by your name and surname. Second, your code works well but one thing, in the first two columns, it shows NULL when there isn´t any value, and i would like to show 0. Is possible to do that?

Comment: @AlonsoGonzálezNestal - you can use IFNULL(qua.media, 0) to get a value of 0 if qua.media is null.

Comment: I saw another problem :(, i saw that there are some qualifications average that show 0 and they have a qualification. It seems to be that occured when misses, attitude, delays and misses_justif are 0...

Comment: At this point it would be great a data sample on a sqlfiddle. I think  this is happening because of that there are missing value from incidents (as it is a left join) and this `qua.id_trimester=incidents.id_trimester` is causing such problem. Maybe fi you return to the old select with subselect as you originally posted maybe it will work. But in order to help you better would be nice to have the sqlfiddle.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - the check for id_trimester is still in the where clause. This negates the LEFT OUTER JOIN, making it an INNER JOIN in effect. If it is moved to the WHERE clause of the sub query it may help. But an Sqlfiddle would make things easier.

Comment: @Kickstart Sorry by my delay, i was creating the sqlfiddle. Here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223122/4

Comment: @JorgeCampos It doesn´t show the pupils 141 and 143 because they haven´t incidents...

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes! It works! A lot of thanks Jorge!! :)

Comment: Minor one - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac255/1 . Note that this will give a row for a pupil who has an incident in trimester 1 but no qualifications in trimester 1 (I modified pupil 144s qualifications to put them into trimester 2 to show this)

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart, you should post as an answer, I will upvote you.

Comment: Don't worry. @JorgeCampos has done 95% of the work and deserves the credit.